# elpy + vagrant + virtualenv, is it possible?

Tags: python, emacs, vagrant, virtualenv

I'd like to use elpy when working on Python stuff in emacs, but with the following twist: my virtualenv for my main project is actually in a vagrant box. I can edit files directly on the vagrant box using `vagrant-tramp` just fine (not actually necessary since the folder w/ the source is synced), but running `elpy-config` picks up an unrelated virtualenv, for a totally different project.

Is there a way to convince elpy to communicate with a python interpreter, and use a virtualenv, on the vagrant box? Or can anyone recommend an alternative setup here?

Answer (score 0):

You can activate your `venv` in vagrant using `pyvenv-activate` command.

```
M-x pyvenv-activate RET /vagrant:box|sudo:box:/path/to/venv RET
```

You can activate it automatically by using any hooks depending on your packages.

**Update:**
Quoting elpy authors comment [from here](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv/issues/26):

> I'm afraid that won't work. Tramp does a lot of magic with Emacs internals to do what it does, but it breaks in interesting ways if you try to tweak it too far. Elpy does that, because it runs so many different processes and needs to communicate with them in various ways.
>
> So, sorry, elpy does not work with tramp. I can highly recommend not using tramp but use sshfs instead for remote file editing. Or, even better, edit locally and use fab/git to deploy to your VM.

Comment: elpy does not like that---elpy-config will pick up on the newly activated virtualenv, but it won't find the python interpreter using `executable-find`, and it won't be able to call the intepreter using `call-process`, to get its configuration.

Comment: it is bug in elpy & i reported it here  http://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv/issues/26 & http://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/497 it will be fixed soon. if you use virtualenvwrapper==3.4 it should work.